# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger - Custom formatting of logging properties

Tags: .net, logging, ilogger, microsoft.extensions.logging

Without creating a brand new customer `ILogger` type, is it possible to somehow register "formatters" for different parameter types?

Example:

```cs
double someVar = 10.3;
/*snip*/

logger.LogDebug("Look at this property {MyProp}", someVar);
```

Can I somehow change how the `someVar` in this case is formatted by the logger?
AFAIK, it just defaults to `ToString()` on each of the provided property values.

In my specific case, I want to change how protobuf messages are logged in properties.
So I would like to intercept the formatting of any `IMessage` object, and apply custom formatting to those. using any existing logger that is.
Is that possible?